# Cannot connect to AWS EC2 using private key sent to myself (Permission denied: public key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, private-key

I know this is an issue that is common but I believe the cause in my case is not the usual.

I have an ubuntu AWS EC2 instance that I access using the private key on my mac.

I wanted access whilst I'm at work so I put the key in my dropbox account and downloaded it onto my work (windows) pc and placed in the `C:/Users/[myusername]/.ssh` directory. I also `chmod 600`'d it.

I'm using the Git shell for ssh as it has SSH and I don't want to install putty for now.

So I run the command

```
C:\Users\[myusername]\.ssh> ssh -v -i .\key_pair.pem ubuntu@[redacted].compute.amazonaws.com
```

(with the correct dns name of course.)

Here is the output:

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to [redacted].compute.amazonaws.com [[redacted]] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .\\key_pair.pem type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
Warning: Permanently added '[redacted].compute.amazonaws.com,[redacted]' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\[myusername]\\.ssh\\github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .\\key_pair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm sure that the key I used is correct as it works on my Mac. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
I notice the debug output mentions:

```
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\[myusername]\\.ssh\\github_rsa
```

Does the fact that it's offering an unrelated public key affect authentication?

Comment: What are the log lines in your `/var/log/auth.log` when the login attempts failed?

Comment: Have you changed the username and groupname of the keyfile to the current acces user of the client machine ? Also change the keyfile permission to 400 and try again

Comment: Given I am not on a UNIX machine do I have a `var/log` directory?

Comment: @Sathish no I haven't change the username/groupname. I simply downloaded it from my dropbox and tried to use it. `chmod 400` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Please change the username and groupname to your current username of the machine and try again

Comment: Actually, checking the file's properties it seem the owner is the current user on the machine

Answer (score 0):

**`.\key_pair.pem`** is wrong.

Use **`./key_pair.pem`** instead with Git bash (it doesn't matter whether you are on windows)

Comment: this makes no difference

Comment: Are you sure uploading the key to dropbox and downloading it from their did not change the key? could you check md5checksum of the key with that off the original key?

Comment: I will try, but it's unlikely. It's just a text file so the content shouldn't've changed.